# covert number strings with leading zeros to numeric value with leading zero in postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, number-formatting, numeric, postgresql-12

i am new to PostgreSQL.i want to convert string '0480' to number 0480 .i am using casting operator to do this,

```
db=# select '0480':: numeric;

 numeric 
---------
     480
(1 row)
```

but here I am expecting 0480 number. Then i tried to_number function in PostgreSQL,

```
db=# select to_number('0480','9999');

 to_number 
-----------
       480
(1 row)
```

so how is this possible? how can I convert number strings with leading zeros to numeric value with leading zero.

also some outputs of to_char function, little bit confusing?

```
db=# select to_char(0480,'9999');

 to_char 
---------
   480
(1 row)

db=# select to_char(0480,'09999');

 to_char 
---------
  00480
(1 row)
```

Using PostgreSQL 12.3 on Debian

Comment: Numbers don't have leading zeros...when you add leading zeros, numbers become strings.  Please explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: There is no such thing as *number 0480*. Numbers don't have leading zeros. String representations of numbers can have the leading zeros, which are typically used to make them all the same length.

Comment: i just want to store phone numbers,so as @KenWhite mentioned , i have to store it as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers don't have leading zeros. `0480` is **exactly** the same number as `480` - just like `00000001` is exactly the same number as `1`

The only way to get leading zeros, is to convert the number to a string and add the desired number of leading zeros.

> *some outputs of to_char function, little bit confusing?*

Not, not at all.

`to_char(0480,'9999')` converts the number `480` to a 4 character string. The `9` indicates that if there is no value for that digit, it can be "dropped".

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)

> 9 - digit position (can be dropped *if insignificant*)
> 0 - digit position (will *not be dropped*, even if insignificant)

Leading zeros are always insignificant (from a mathematical perspective).

`to_char(480,'0000')` will do you what you expect: a four digit string with a leading zero. 
Similarly `to_char(1,'0000')` will return `0001`.

Note that by default, all output of `to_char()` is right-aligned with leading spaces. If you don't want that, you should use the `FM` modifier: e.g. `to_char(1,'FM0000')`